# SQL query help: bring data where the field is not empty

Tags: mysql

I am getting data via the google plus api and saving it in database.

The field text is empty in certain rows like this[image: LIKE THIS]

i will be using the text field for sentiment analysis. what will be the sql query to only get fields where the text field is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you describe as "empty" means `NULL` (rather than `''` (i.e. empty string)), then use

```
WHERE text IS NULL
```

at the end of your query. If it's actually an empty string (NULL would be a better way to store it, but sometimes you have to work with imperfect data), then you'd have to use

```
WHERE text = ''
```

instead.

Comment: I actually wanted to get text field when it was not empty. I just added "<>" in your code and it worked so thanks.

Comment: Ah ok. Your question says "what will be the sql query to only get fields where the text field is empty?", hence why I gave the answer like that. I see now that the question as shown in the title says the opposite. Glad it has helped, anyway. P.S. Personally I would advise you to store empty values like this as NULL instead, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM t WHERE text =''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_names
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```

[See docs here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)